# Embedding a report in Entity Framework or an alternative to reporting services?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor, reporting-services

I have built a webapp for the company I work for, and I need the ability to quickly generate parameterized reports that can be exported to CSV, Excel, PDF, etc. Obviously, my first go-to was to use reporting services provided by SQL Server, but it seems to be coming up short for cross browser support, and embedding in razor views.

Is there any information out there on how to make this work smoothly, or possibly alternate frameworks I can look into to make generating these reports more simple?

Answer (score 0):

ssrs has web services which do not need any browser (if it's just about generating a file output)

or there is a asp.net web control, but it will probably not be much better for cross-browser support
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx